# What is the java 7 equivalent to SomeClass::compareTo expression?

Tags: java, comparator

My intention was to create a custom sorting method:

```
public void mySort
{
    this.sort(SomeClass::compareTo());
}
```

This worked perfectly fine in Java 8, however, Java 7 is angry! Do I even need a custom sorting method or will the sort() method take care of it if the objects (SomeClass) inside the customized ArrayList (referred to by *this*) have a predefined comparator built into them?

Comment: A little more context, please. Where is this defined (i.e., what is `this`)?

Comment: A customized container that extends ArrayList that implements List.

Comment: pass a reference to a Comparator object, which is is new SomeClass()

Comment: Lambda expressions such as SomeClass::compareTo() where only introduced in Java 8.

Comment: I know that :). Hence why I said Java 7 equivalent silly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions above did not end up working with my implementation. That said, Collections.sort(this.myList) worked wonders. Thanks for your suggestions though!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`List.sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) says that if you pass in `null`, then the list will be sorted according it it's *natural ordering*. So, if your class implements `Comparable`, you should be able to pass in `null`.

The definition of *natural ordering* as per the `Comparable` interface docs:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as its natural comparison method.

Comment: So essentially, I can forgo the method altogether and sort the customized container via .sort() without any fear?

Comment: Yeah. But I suggest you run some tests to verify for yourself.

Comment: So, when I removed the mySort(), it could not find the symbol for sort()!

Comment: Did you mean to use `sort(null)`? Of course `sort()` doesn't exist on `List`.

Comment: Yup. So what would go inside the sort()?

Comment: I've already said `null` twice now. Also refer to the documentation for the method...

Comment: That did not end up working for me. However, what ended up solving the problem was using the Collections.sort(this.myList);